# Layered navigation block v2.1.2 - can not make it visible prestashop

Tags: filter, prestashop

This module is installed on Prestashop, appears in a position on my back office and I have configured, but not in my front office.

How to make it visible?

The website is: [a2alabels.com](http://a2alabels.com)

Comment: it's visible: check http://a2alabels.com/index.php?id_category=12&controller=category on the left column. the "Catalog" block it's your block layered module. If you mean that it's not visible in your homepage it's becouse the module hasn't got that functionality, it shows only in the category tpl.

Comment: Thanks, but how will show on homepage?

Comment: Please help me i shall be very thankful